# Meta page gave me a 404

Tags: bug

This is a bit of an odd one, but I clicked a link in the hot meta posts panel and was taken to a 404 page:

[image: 404 Screenshot]

Note that link isn't using SSL, perhaps that is relevant?

Refreshing (simply pressing F5) did bring up the page properly (though now with the redirect to the HTTPS version) though and I can't replicate the issue again. I've got nothing clever sat in between me and the SO server (e.g. proxy server, funky firewall) so unless my ISP has some transparent strangeness it's look like an SO problem?

(Note: I've tagged this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) even though I can't reproduce it again, perhaps it should be [support](/questions/tagged/support) instead?)

Comment: Very strange, as we have custom 404 pages too - they don't look like this. You might have hit the site mid-deploy.

Comment: I saw it once before, perhaps 3 or 4 months ago but I wasn't sure if it was something I'd done or not so never mentioned it. Could be a red herring though. Mid-deploy is a good option, perhaps you can tie that in to the time of this question, hard to be specific but I would say 10-20 minutes before I posted this?

Comment: The urls in the Hot Meta Posts bulletin  are all http and not https. Other links are all https. That shouldn't be a problem but it explains why you end up on a non-ssl page.

Comment: @rene Yeah, I knew that, just thought it was worth mentioning in case it helped debug the problem.

Comment: @rene the code for the hot meta posts is now fixed, should be updated as soon as the caches expire (see on superuser.com where I've invalidated the cache manually)

Comment: @m0sa verified here on MSO and that works as expected now (as in hrefs are https). Thanks!