# Question briefly returned a basic 404 page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, 404-not-found

I attempted to add a tag to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357318/stack-overflow-trends-is-it-only-about-questions), and got an error message "an error occurred" or something like that.

Reloading the page showed this basic 404 page:

> [image: 404 page]

A few moments later, the question was available again and the edit succeeded.

Perhaps you were fiddling with something and broke the site for a very short period? Anyway, here's a bug report just in case.

Comment: There is a certain mount of wobble on the sites today - there is some maintenance effort going on.

Comment: I had this friday just gone on meta and main.

Comment: [Happened to me in May](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349377/meta-page-gave-me-a-404), potential duplicate?

Comment: @DavidG yeah, given that I don't have any additional info available, I'm fine with closing this as a duplicate of your question.